# sql count and sum in the same statement

Tags: sql, oracle, count, group-by, sum

How do I do something like the following, I basically need to count the total of applications and then divide it by sum of another column.

Here's my query,

```
 select TIME_ID, CAMPUSID, GenderId, FEETYPEID, PrefRankId, QUALIFID, PRIMARYSTUDYFIELD, SUPSTUDYFIELD,IsYear12Id, COURSEID
        , count(APPID) as TOT_NUM_APP, sum(ATAR) as TOT_ATAR, round(SUM(ATAR)/(SUM(COUNT(APPID)) OVER () ) AS TOT_ATAR_AVG
      from temp_fact tf1
      group by TIME_ID, CAMPUSID, GenderId, FEETYPEID, PrefRankId, QUALIFID, 
                PRIMARYSTUDYFIELD, SUPSTUDYFIELD,IsYear12Id,courseid;
```

See the above query. But it's wrong, cause I want the average of ATAR which is  TOT_NUM_APP/TOT_ATAR

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you need a subquery.  Can you supply sample data and desired results?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and desired results?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name haha i made a mistake...all good..thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most databases support window functions.  So, if I understand correctly, `sum(count(appid))` is supposed to represent the total count across all the rows.  If so:

```
SELECT TIME_ID, CAMPUSID, GenderId, FEETYPEID, PrefRankId, QUALIFID, PRIMARYSTUDYFIELD,
       SUPSTUDYFIELD, IsYear12Id, courseid , count(APPID) as TOT_NUM_APP,
       SUM(ATAR)/(SUM(COUNT(APPID)) OVER ()) as TOT_STUD_ATAR
FROM temp_fact tf1
GROUP BY TIME_ID, CAMPUSID, GenderId, FEETYPEID, PrefRankId, QUALIFID, PRIMARYSTUDYFIELD,
         SUPSTUDYFIELD, IsYear12Id, courseid;
```